# Including full non-lifting body workouts

Tags: training

I've been quite enjoying my tiring lifting routines, and I feel really good about developing muscle and strength, **but** I still want to lose body fat, not really for looking slimmer, just to look more toned. I was wondering if I could do my 3 day routine on Monday, Wednesday and Friday while having some full body workouts on Tuesdays and Thursdays without involving any lifting, and focus more on reps and body-weight exercises. Is this advisable? if so, I read swimming is one the best full body exercises, but I have no access to a pool. What would be some replacements for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally have found complexes with a barbell or small 15 min Cross Fit  WODs to be very effective in getting 'toned' in addition to changing my diet. - done after main workout.

But if you want a full-body movement without barbells that is taxing a lot muscles I would say burpees, hill-sprints and even rope-skipping or prowler pushing (if available ) are a valid substitute.

Comment: WODs? I'm not familiar with the terminology

Comment: @PoolPartyRenekton: WOD = *Workout of the Day*

Answer (score 1):

I’m biased, but, if you have access to one, I would urge you to take a look at using a rower for a full body workout.  Done with correct form, you can get an entire workout experience from strength to aerobics.  You can train for endurance, intensity, etc.  Most good rowing machines come with a performance monitor so you can track your progress.

> "Rowing machines provide the best total-body workout of any cardio
>   machine," says U.S. Olympic rowing coach Mike Teti. This is because
>   they require equal effort from both your lower and your upper body,
>   which could lead to greater gains in overall cardiovascular fitness.

([Blast fat exercise machines](http://www.menshealth.com/fitness/blast-fat-exercise-machines))

If you decide to try a rower, make sure to get proper instruction.  Learning how to use a rower correctly will help you avoid injury and allow you to gain full benefit from the machine.